# Loading Spinner activates on every button on the page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to integrate a loading spinner into a button. This also works very well. The problem: If I click on a button, the spinner will respond to every additional button.

How can I correct this?

**My code:**

```
<button ion-button block (click)="loading = true">
  <ion-spinner class="whiteSpinner" item-left *ngIf="loading" name="bubbles"></ion-spinner>
  Buy now - 1,49€
</button>
```

The other buttons like the same...

Image to show you what I mean:

Comment: maybe because all the buttons use the same `loading` property from the component? can you add the code for the component that contains those buttons?

Comment: Yes, that´s right. All buttons uses the same loading property. But buttons are loading dynamically, so I can´t give unique propertys. Any idea?

Comment: Do you use ngFor to generate all you buttons ? In this case, loading property is true for all buttons.

Comment: the `loading` property needs to be created for each instance of your button, you should probably wrap the header, content and the button as standalone component with the loading property

Comment: Man.. show us the code which u used to generate the buttons dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have bunch of dynamic buttons you can add unique id to them. Even if you use for example `*ngFor` to generate all buttons they will have unique ids different from in this case `myButton`.

```
<button #myButton ion-button block (click)="myButton.loading = true">
  <ion-spinner class="whiteSpinner" item-left *ngIf="myButton.loading" name="bubbles"></ion-spinner>
  Buy now - 1,49€
</button>
```

Comment: Many thanks, that´s nice! But how I can set loading to false again in my component after running a function?

Comment: Save your button to component by passing it as parameter to onClick() function and reuse it when needed

Comment: myButton is not an ID , it is template variable..how do you generate that dynamically using *ngFor? @Yevgen