# Spinner loads for every button when clicked on a specific button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have implemented an ion spinner and an icon inside a single button which acts as a download button. 
When the page loads only the download icon is visible and when a user clicks on it the download icon is hidden and the spinner shows up. I have used ngFor to show multiple download buttons.

I am facing an issue when i click on a specific button, all the spinner starts to load rather than the specific button spinner.

Here is my code

```
          <ion-list>
            <div class="chip" *ngFor="let attachment of Trade.attachment">
              <div class="chip-content">
                <ion-label style="font-weight: 500;">{{attachment.attachment_file_name}}</ion-label>
              </div>
              <div class="chip-close">
                <button  #downloadButton ion-button clear color="dark"
                  (click)="download(attachment.attachment_file_name,attachment.attachment_id,downloadButton.isLoading = true)">
                  <ion-icon name="arrow-down" md="md-arrow-round-down" *ngIf="!downloadButton.isLoading" color="primary"></ion-icon>
                  <ion-spinner class="downloadspinner" name="crescent" *ngIf="downloadButton.isLoading"> </ion-spinner>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ion-list>
```

I have tried the solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461159/loading-spinner-activates-on-every-button-on-the-page). It works but i am not able to stop the spinner when my function is complete.

How do i load a spinner specific to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead  `downloadButton.isLoading` use `attachment.isLoading` . This will store data in row when button is click

Create one item in attachement as isLoading. Default value will be `false`. When you click on button make it true and once process is done make it again false.

Change it like below. No need to pass isLoading into function. I have changed it to row instead. With that you can change that particular row value to false.

```
(click)="download(attachment.attachment_file_name,attachment.attachment_id, attachment);attachment.isLoading = true;"
```

in your typescript function

```
download(file, id, attachement_row) {
    //Once your downloading done
    attachement_row.isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: I added an isLoading  = false item in attachment and now i make it true on the click of the button like =download(attachment.attachment_file_name,attachment.attachment_id,attachment.isLoading = true)
this starts the button specific spinner but now how do i close it in my typescript file?

Comment: I am getting this error - TypeError: Cannot set property 'isLoading ' of undefined
I debugged the the function and the parameter value of attachement_row is 'undefined'

Comment: Make sure you changed into HTML as well. There its passing third argument as attachment.

Comment: Ah! I missed the 3rd argument. This works great! Thanks a ton!